# Unable to select the cell contains today's date

Tags: vba, excel

I am consolidating the daily report sent by my team in a single file named as "Master file" it will have each sheet separately for each of my team members. i need to find the cell contains today's date in a report sent by my team member and copy the corresponding cells and paste it in the "Master file"
Here is the code

```
Sub Copy_data()
    Sheets("Daily Report").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    Dim mydate As Date
    mydate = Range("B1")
    For i = 1 To 4 'this is sample actually i have 38 sheets
    Dim filename As Variant
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    filename = ActiveCell.Value
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\test\Desktop\AP\" & filename
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=mydate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate ' this is where i get an error as "object variable or with block variable not set"

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    Dim currentcell As Integer
    currentcell = ActiveCell.Row
    Range(Selection, Cells(currentcell, 10)).Copy
    Windows("Agent Performance.xls").Activate
    Dim sheetname As String
    sheetname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Sheets(sheetname).Select

    'Here again i have to find the cell with today's date and paste the data which i copied    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Note :- It was working fine in the earlier stage. After making few changes in the  format and appearance, also added all the sheets in the "master file" after then i am getting this error !! Also i am beginner to VBA, kindly pardon me for any flaws.

Comment: Instead of `xlFormulas` look in `xlValues`

Comment: Thanks for the reply however getting the same error !!

Comment: What error and on what line?

Comment: On the same line "  Cells.Find(What:=mydate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate"

Comment: @David what is the error code and error name provided by the system?

Comment: run-time error '91'

Comment: [You should avoid using `.Activate`/`.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: I believe this is what you meant " Cells.Find(What:=JesusB, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select"  but sorry no luck it throws the same error !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going out on a limb, I tried to fix up your code and avoid all the `.Select`/`.Activate`, which can cause some headaches.

In your OP I don't see where you go to paste, so made an educated guess at the end, and noted as such.

Step through this with `F8` to make sure it's working properly, as you can then follow it one line at a time.

```
Sub Copy_data()
Dim newWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook, agentWB As Workbook
Dim dailyWS As Worksheet, dashWS As Worksheet
Dim i       As Long
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim currentcell As Integer
Dim destSheetname As String


Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook
Set dailyWS = currentWB.Sheets("Daily Report")
Dim mydate  As Date
mydate = dailyWS.Range("B1")
For i = 1 To 4               'this is sample actually i have 38 sheets
    Dim filename As Variant
    filename = dailyWS.Range("A7").Offset(1, 0).Value
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test\Desktop\AP\" & filename)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Set dashWS = newWB.Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set foundCell = dashWS.Cells.Find(What:=mydate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    currentcell = foundCell.Offset(0, 2).Row
    dashWS.Range(foundCell.Offset(0, 2), dashWS.Cells(currentcell, 10)).Copy
    Set agentWB = Workbooks("Agent Performance.xls")
    destSheetname = agentWB.Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value 'Do you know the activesheet name? If so use it here instead.
    agentWB.Sheets(destSheetname).Activate
    ''' Is this where you want to paste??
    agentWB.Sheets(destSheetname).Range("A1").Paste

    'Here again i have to find the cell with today's date and paste the data which i copied
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bruce for your extended help !!! I really appreciate it !! It worked !!!

Comment: @David - Glad it worked! FYI I think what I did was mainly get rid of the `.Select`/`.Activate` and used variables to work directly with the data.  I believe your main error was you can't do `.Select` with `Cells.Find()`.  That's why I set a Range variable to be equal to the `.Find()`. You *could* after that line do `foundCell.Select` if you really wanted to select it, FYI.  But there's usually not a need to actually select a cell (although I do use `.Select` often when debugging with `F8` to make sure the right cells are being used).

Comment: (@David - if it did work, you can flag it as "the answer" by clicking the check mark left of the post, under the up/down arrows).